# How do I combine rows in Open Refine

Tags: openrefine

I am very new at open refine and I am seeking to combine rows and columns in a spreadsheet with many duplicate values. Please find the example I am looking for below. I think it has to do with the "fill down" command, but I am not sure. Thank you very much!

```
    Original Table      New Table

    Name | Totals       Name|Totals
    -----|-------       ----|------
    A        5            A    15
    A        10           B    104
    B        1            C    219
    B        3
    B        100
    C        4
    C        150
    C        65
    C        0
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to this question but matches the title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677751/how-to-merge-rows-in-openrefine

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is basically a [pivot table](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html). It's way much simpler to do in a spreadsheet software (like Excel). But it's still feasible in OpenRefine.

- make sure that the column "Name" is in the first position and that its values are sorted.
- Use `blank down` in this column.
- Create a new column from "Totals" and use this formula:

`row.record.cells.Totals.value.sum()`

- Using a `filter by blank`, keep only the "Names" rows that contain a value.
- Export the filtered rows in .csv or .xlsx.

This screencast will make things clearer.

[image]